# Proof of polynomial equation

Tags: solution-verification

I'd like to prove that $a^n + b^n = c^n$ where $n>2$ and $a>0$, $b>0$, and $c>0$ has no solution.

I first divided each by $a$, then I get $c>a$.
Then, I divided each by $b$, then I get $c>b$.

Finally, I divide each by $c$, then I get $(a/c)^n + (b/c)^n = 1$.
Because if $n$ infinitely increases, $(a/c)^n + (b/c)^n$ is $0$. Thus, there are no values that satisfy the equation.

I think my proof is somewhat awkward. Can anybody help solve this?

Comment: I found a solution:  $1^3+2^3=(\sqrt[3]3^2)^3$

Comment: How about $\sqrt[3]{4}^3+\sqrt[3]{4}^3=2^3$?

Comment: I honestly don't understand the amount of downvotes given neither the close votes. The question is clearly stated, an attempted proof is given adn the OP is trying to figure out what's wrong with it. Even though he missed some "easy" counterexamples this is a fine question.

Comment: Is this Fermat’s Last Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt of proof has a problem in quantification. The problem is in this passage:

"Because if $n$ infinitely increases, $(a/c)^n+(b/c)^n$ is $0$''. You can only do this if $\forall n>2:(a/c)^n+(b/c)^n=1$, while you only have the hypothesis $\exists n>2:(a/c)^n+(b/c)^n=1$.

In other words, what are you trying to prove is:

If $\exists a,b,c>0:\exists n>2:a^n+b^n=c^n$, then $\bot$,

where $\bot$ stand for contradiction. But you only proved that:

If $\exists a,b,c>0:\forall n>2:a^n+b^n=c^n$, then $\bot$.